# Even if the img is in a separate div, it doesn't show up

Tags: html, css

Experiencing problem in positioning an image. Look, I have made two columns in one div. Every of them has 50% width. Why the image doesn't appear in the second column, even if there's enough space for it? How to make it go to the second column? Into the `.imgDiv`

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/awxsqLbc/

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
body {} .container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: lightblue
}
.content {
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 10px;
  min-height: 50vh;
  min-width: 70%;
}
.msgDiv {
  width: 50%;
}
.imgDiv {
  width: 50%;
}
.imgDiv img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">

    <div class="msgDiv">
      <h1>Welcome.</h1>
      <h2>Are you hungry?  </h2>
      <h3>Start</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="imgDiv">
      <img src="http://moderndogmagazine.com/sites/default/files/styles/blog_top_image/public/images/blogs/top_images/nb_seal_04_2.jpg?itok=DR7IOsFi" alt="" />
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you maybe using bootstrap.css ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to .content:

```
display:flex;
align-items:center;
```

fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/awxsqLbc/1/

Answer (score 0):

that's because you set `display: flex` to `.container`, not `.content`

update your code and it should work

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to your problem. You want the picture to be beside the text. You should try using float style in your CSS. This solution is simpler than the other answers.

Try this. It should work:

CSS:

```
 .container {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: lightblue
}
.content {
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius: 10px;
    min-height: 50vh;
    min-width: 70%;
}

.msgDiv {
  width: 50%;
  margin:0;
  float:left;
}

.imgDiv {
  width: 50%;
  float:right;
}

.imgDiv img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

HTML (*Same HTML as your old code*):

```
<div class="container">
<div class="content">

<div class="msgDiv">
<h1>Welcome.</h1>
<h2>Are you hungry?  </h2>
<h3>Start</h3>
</div>

<div class="imgDiv">
<img src="http://moderndogmagazine.com/sites/default/files/styles/blog_top_image/public/images/blogs/top_images/nb_seal_04_2.jpg?itok=DR7IOsFi" alt="" />
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to your columns `float:left;`

```
.msgDiv {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.imgDiv {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```